# How to connect securely to VNC server? (x11vnc)

Tags: arch-linux, ssl, manjaro, vnc, x11vnc

I'm using **Manjaro / Arch Linux** distribution. I'm trying to connect securely to my VNC server, but I'm not able to configure it.

I'm using **x11vnc**, because It's much optimal than TigerVNC for streaming the current user session.

Using this command I'm able to start my VNC server:

```
x11vnc -nap -wait 50 -noxdamage -rfbauth /home/mikel/.vnc/passwd -display :0 -nocursor -forever
```

But when I use (Real) VNC Viewer it says that the connection is not secure.

[image]

I want to connect to the VNC Server from outside the LAN, so the connection must be encrypted.

I tried using the `-ssl` flag. This flag generates a ssl cert and uses it. VNC Viewer **is NOT compatible** with this kind of VNC Connections, so I had to download [this one (ssvnc)](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/#downloading).

After trying to connect using this program, I get this error on my server console:

```
20/11/2019 21:44:55 SSL: ssl_helper[1688]: SSL_accept() *FATAL: -1 SSL FAILED
20/11/2019 21:44:55 SSL: error:1420918C:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:version too low
```

And this error on my Windows VNC Viewer:

[image]

I don't know if *x11vnc* is not working or if the VNC Viewer(*ssvnc*) has an outdated library.

¿Any suggestion?

Comment: [`x11vnc` has several options to enable encryption](https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc), such as `-vencrypt`, `-anontls` and many `-ssl*` options.  If you can find the running `x11vnc` process, you should be able to see if it has SSL configured by examining the process's arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ssh` and port forwarding to set up a tunnel. You log into the remote host (example.com) with a command like this:

```
ssh -L 5903:localhost:5900 user@example.com
```

Then, you connect `vncserver` to *localhost:3*

The -L swich forwards the local port 5903 to the remote host, that will then forward it (from its side) to localhost:0.

`vncserver thinks it is talking to localhost:3 and that is not encrypted, but the ssh traffic from localhost:3 to remotehost:0 (the tunnel over the internet) is encrypted, so you are all set.

Since `ssh` also compresses your traffic, you might get a (small) boost from that too.